# I'm so confused with linear transformation of curves (e.g. ellipse) and change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, plane-geometry, change-of-basis, change-of-variable

I was thinking about how to rotate an ellipse in the xy plane by 30 degrees anticlockwise.

In the below diagram, I was thinking of fixing the original coordiate system xy and expressing the equation in x'y' plane $$\frac{x'^2}{a^2} + \frac{y'^2}{b^2} = 1$$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

[image]

So I substituted $$x'= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} x - \frac{1}{2} y$$ and $$y' = \frac{1}{2} x + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} y$$

for a = 4 and b = 3 but the result is:

[image]

The opposite of what I expected. At what point am I confused?

Comment: In your first picture, the positive $y$-axis, where $x=0$ and $y>0$, is in the first quadrant of the $x'$-$y'$-plane.  So points on the positive $y$-axis should have both $x'$ and $y'$ positive. But your formulas expressing $x'$ and $y'$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ would give those points negative $x'$ values. So your formulas don't match your sketch.  I think you probably just reversed the sign of $\theta$ and thus got the minus sign on the wrong $\frac12$ in your formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formulae works for rotating the points about the origin . In your case you have rotated the axes counter-clockwise by 30° , so the respective points in the plane have been rotated CLOCKWISE , so you have to rather take the negative value of tha angle rather than the positive value .

Comment: Capital letters are the equivalent of shouting on the Internet. Is this what you have intended?

Comment: That isn't a rule , is it ? And no I didn't intend to be it like that @TobyMak

Comment: I would suggest using italics instead like *this* (two asterisks on either side).